# Setting element.style.left using calc() in JavaScript does not work when calculations are involved

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

and in my JavaScript code, I am trying to set its `left` property value to the result of a calculation. This same calculation works in CSS but not when used in JavaScript code.

```
var element = document.getElementById("container");

element.style.left = "calc(" + (container.clientWidth + containerUnit + " / 2 - " + child.clientWidth + unit + " / 2") + ");";
```

But, `console.log(element.style.left)` returns: (blank value here). And upon setting this style in JS, no effect is made on the element.

`containerUnint` contains "px" and `unit` contains "%"

Comment: Just calculate the value and set the value to the element style. You don't need the "calc" statement.

Comment: @Archer That results in the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're passing an invalid value to `calc()`, so the browser is not applying it. You have to specify measurements for CSS to understand how to actually execute the calculation.

Your current concatenation compiles to something like:

```
calc(200 / 2 - 10 / 2);
```

I guess you're working in pixels, so you need to update your definition as follows:

```js
element.style.left = "calc(" + (container.clientWidth + containerUnit + "px / 2 - " + child.clientWidth + unit + "px / 2") + ")";
```

Notice that you should also lose the trailing `;`:

```js
const element = document.getElementById("container");

const containerUnit = '%';
const unit = 'px';

element.style.left = "calc(" + (10 + containerUnit + " / 2 - " + 10 + unit + " / 2") + ")";

console.log(element.style.left)
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Since % and px are units of measurement, I am using containerUnit for % and px and unit for % and px.

Comment: That wouldn't matter, you just have to ensure that your `calc()` definition is syntactically correct.

Comment: the result of my calculation is 100px / 2 - 10% / 2. Which works in CSS.

Comment: @Jay Please see my edit, it still works.

Comment: due to concatenation in JS. `child.clientWidth` equals `10` and `unint == "%"`, so the result of that concatenation is: `"10%"`.

Comment: @Jay yes, I realised after writing that what you were referring to, sorry. Anyway, please see my updated answer, which shows this works.

Comment: Thank you, this does still form a valid output, however once I put the calculations in-place, the result is blank.

Comment: `child.style.left = "calc(" + (container.clientWidth / 2 + containerUnit + child.clientWidth / 2 + unit) + ")";`

Comment: You're missing some parentheses: `child.style.left = "calc(" + ((container.clientWidth / 2) + containerUnit) + ((child.clientWidth / 2) + unit) + ")";`